# I cannot insert a pdf document to my texworks file

Tags: pdftex, pdf, pdfpages

I am trying to insert a multipaged pdf file (file B) at the end of my pdf generated through texworks (file A). The pdf B that I am trying to add is quite big (and both the pdf and the tex files are in the same folder)> I tried the following command in a separate tex file..when it works nicely, but when I am trying to do the same in my working tex document, I can still typeset document A, but I get error messages like this (Undefined control sequence.l.91 \includepdf
[pages=-]{thesis.pdf}) and the pdf B is not merged to doc A..how can I solve this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
fillerwordfillerwordfillerword
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\includepdf[pages=-]{thesis.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Show the complete error message from the log file correctly formatted as code.

Comment: I am quite new to texworks, not sure where to get the code from, bad boxes/errors tab?

Comment: The log is a file, you can simply open it and then copy and paste.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have `\usepackage{pdfpages}` in your preamble i.e. before `\begin{document}`. At least your example doesn't need the `final` parameter to be loaded with package `pdfpages`. You don't need to have `thesis.tex` in your working directory. Just having `thesis.pdf` shall suffice. Try the following snippet.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
fillerwordfillerwordfillerword

\includepdf[pages=-]{thesis.pdf}
\end{document}
```